# How to change default value of "Disable Touch Simulation" in Firefox Dev Tools?

Tags: firefox, devtools, responsive-design-view

Windows 10, Firefox 70.0.1.

When I enable the Responsive Design Mode in the Dev Tools, the "Disable Touch Simulation" is on by default.  Even when I turn it off, then close and open the Responsive Design Mode, it is switched back on.  It is an annoying behavior, because the site I'm working on ignores all mouse events with this option on; and it's been off by default until very recently.

I'd like for the "Disable Touch Simulation" to be off by default.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

In case you're still struggling with this after two months:

There doesn't seem to be a way to completely turn of touch simulation, but it is enabled because the device that Firefox emulates has a touch screen. 
What you can do is open the device list (top left when responsive design mode is opened), click on "edit list" and than on "Add custom device...". There you can create a device without touch screen.

The fields are prefilled with the last device you emulated, so if you have selected the device you want to use before creating the custom one, all you need to do is disable the "touch screen" checkbox.